# Star graph x- and y-coordinate problem

Tags: diagrams, graphs, tkz-berge

I can put multiple `\grComplete`s in a tikzpicture, and space them out nicely. But when I try to do the same thing with `\grStar`, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Here's a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

These complete graphs are spread out nicely.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Simple];
  \node[align=center] at (0,0.5) {$K_1$};
  \grComplete[x=0,y=0,RA=0]{1};
  \node[align=center] at (3,0.5) {$K_2$};
  \grComplete[x=3,y=0,RA=1]{2};
  \node[align=center] at (6,1.5) {$K_3$};
  \grComplete[x=6,y=0,RA=1]{3};
  \node[align=center] at (9,1.5) {$K_4$};
  \grComplete[x=9,y=0,RA=1]{4};
  \node[align=center] at (12,1.5) {$K_5$};
  \grComplete[x=12,y=0,RA=1]{5};
\end{tikzpicture}

This is supposed to be 5 star graphs, but they are not spread out.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Simple];
  \node[align=center] at (0,0.5) {$S_1$};
  \grStar[x=0,y=0,RA=1]{2};
  \node[align=center] at (3,0.5) {$S_2$};
  \grStar[x=3,y=0,RA=1]{4};
  \node[align=center] at (6,1.5) {$S_3$};
  \grStar[x=6,y=0,RA=1]{4};
  \node[align=center] at (9,1.5) {$S_4$};
  \grStar[x=9,y=0,RA=1]{5};
  \node[align=center] at (12,1.5) {$S_5$};
  \grStar[x=12,y=0,RA=1]{6};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:
[image: latex output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options `x` and `y` seem only to work for certain graphs without a center node. At least for the stars, using `x` and `y` obviously does not shift the center node. The documentation of the package uses scopes to shift graphs in certain cases. Hence, I would suggest you also adhere to this practice at least for the stars:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

These complete graphs are spread out nicely.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Simple];
  \node at (0,0.5) {$K_1$};
  \grComplete[x=0,RA=0]{1};
  \node at (3,0.5) {$K_2$};
  \grComplete[x=3,RA=1]{2};
  \node at (6,1.5) {$K_3$};
  \grComplete[x=6,RA=1]{3};
  \node at (9,1.5) {$K_4$};
  \grComplete[x=9,RA=1]{4};
  \node at (12,1.5) {$K_5$};
  \grComplete[x=12,RA=1]{5};
\end{tikzpicture}

This is supposed to be 5 star graphs, and they are now also spread out nicely.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Simple];
  \node at (0,0.5) {$S_1$};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
    \grStar[RA=0]{2};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (3,0.5) {$S_2$};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \grStar[RA=1]{3};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (6,1.5) {$S_3$};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \grStar[RA=1]{4};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (9,1.5) {$S_4$};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
    \grStar[RA=1]{5};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (12,1.5) {$S_5$};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
    \grStar[RA=1]{6};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an elegant solution, because I can also move the node inside the scope, so I don't have to duplicate the x-coordinate!

Comment: That’s true. Actually, I removed some (at least from my point of view) unnecessary options you used. I hope, you don’t mind. Of course, it is also not necessary to shift something by 0cm, so you can remove the `scope` for the first graph. I only put this there to make the code consistent.